# New window of application on every virtual desktop

Tags: unity, workspaces

I am trying to meet the best functionality for Virtual Desktops on Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know if this is an application-specific question, Docky or Ubuntu in general.

What I would like to do is that every time I switch to another virtual desktop and I try to launch an application, it creates a new instance of it.

Ex. I am working on Desktop #1 in Sublime Text, when I switch to Desktop #2, I want to launch a new instance of Sublime when I click icon on Docky. The functionality now is that it switches me to active window on Desktop #1.

This all works well in Chrome btw.

Is there a way to accomplish this kind of thing?

Thanks in advance